# jqplot generate plot using functions returned values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Sorry for this based question. I am fresh to jqplot and would like to use it to generate a bar graph based on data calculated from a function.

Now, I have a parameter which holds data. Also, I have simple codes to generate a bar plot. So, can anyone give me a hint on how to link these two pieces together?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
x_data=function(a,b,c,d) 
#this is the data generated from a function and it needs to be 
#sent to jqplot function, i.e., x_data=[165.33, 102.9, 89.04, 181.54, 114.92]. 
#In order to pass the parameter to jqplot, do I need to print it out in the HTML?


<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(x_data){
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var s1=x_data; //I need to find a way to link s1 to x_data 

        $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true },
                rendererOptions: {
                barWidth: 3
                }
            }
        })   
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that whatever you are entering as the 2nd parameter of the `$.jqplot()` method, in your case it is `x_pre_irr`, is in the form of, e.g.

`[[[1,2],[2,3],[3,6],[4,5]],[[1,2],[2,3],[3,6],[4,5]]]`.

[You could find more details in the examples here.](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)

**EDIT**
You have few important errors there:

1. With bar chart the `CategoryAxisRenderer` should be used:

   ```
       axes:{
           xaxis: {
               renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
           }
       }
   ```
2. To get stuff inside a HTML tag using `jQuery` you use `text()` (or `html()`)
   method, not `val()` as it returns whatever a tag has in its `value` parameter.
3. Then whatever you will get will be a String thus you must convert it to array of values, e.g. using `$.parseJSON($('#x_pre_irr_val').text());`.

[This is presented in this sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/JWhmQ/223/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the code. However, I still could not generate the bar plot. Could you mind taking a look at my updated code?

Comment: The `x_data` function should be inside the `script` tag. Remove the x_data parameter of the `ready` function. Then you should be fine. If something still doesn't work then check firebug if it says noting then post a working code sample at http://jsfiddle.net presenting your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All my data come from a url address, but I can print them into a html table. Then my plan is to use jquery to get the content of html table. However, I got some issues. Could you mind taking a look at this jsfiddle?http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/220/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there anything I can do if I want a standard bar chart (each data has its own bar, currently, it generates one bar)? Is there any book about jqplot I can look at?

Comment: Check the examples and see how the data is formatted. You would need to put each data in its own series.

Comment: I see. One more question, is there a way to feed jqplot function without writing out all the values as a html table? My data are saved as vectors and they are changed based on different user inputs.

Comment: Thanks again. I should pay attention to the format of [[s1]] or [s1] here is the final update http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/242/ still, it will be great if I can generate bar plot without create a html table first.